# Would 私は怖い mean "I'm scared" or "I'm scary"?

Tags: meaning, i-adjectives, ambiguity

Or does it mean both? If so, is there any way to explicitly distinguish between "I'm scared" and "I'm scary"?
If it only means one and not the other, how would you say the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To give a few working examples:

> **私は**猫が**怖い**。
> **I'm scared** of cats.
>
> 恵美子ちゃんは猫は平気みたいだけど、**私は怖い**らしい。
> Emiko seems to be fine around cats, but apparently is **scared of me**.
>
> **僕は怖い**よ。
> **I'm scary**, just so you know.

That makes 私は怖い officially ambiguous and the answer to your question must be "both, depending on the context".

Comment: Are there any special connotations to 怖い vs. 恐い in your opinion?

Comment: @小太郎 `I'm scared` => `怖い`. `I'm scary` => `私が怖い`.

Comment: @JensJensen That might work as a separate question.