# Who's afraid in 私が怖い?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が

In an anime I heard this sentence:

> どうして私と戦おうとしないの？私**が**怖いの？

which is translated as "Why don't you want to fight me? Are you scared of me?". I'm not sure why `が` is used here: I found that [私**は**怖い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11715/would-%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AF%E6%80%96%E3%81%84-mean-im-scared-or-im-scary) means "I'm scared", and I'd have expected `私が怖い` to have the same meaning, with `私` marked as subject instead that as theme; I tried to read again [the question about those particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C), but I'm not really sure if it applies in this case, since it doen't seem to fit in any of the usages listed.

What role has `が` in this case? If the sentence can mean both "I'm scared" and "[someone is] scared of me", it's context the only way to discriminate?